# Code Implementation of Formula to get a MidPoint Coords between to GPS Positions not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, gps, mapkit

Good day, I'm fairly new to Objective C Dev and am enquiring to an implementation of the midpoint formula located here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

Formula:

Bx = cos(lat2).cos(Δlong)

By = cos(lat2).sin(Δlong)

latm = atan2(sin(lat1) + sin(lat2), √((cos(lat1)+Bx)² + By²))

lonm = lon1 + atan2(By, cos(lat1)+Bx)

My Implementation of this formula in Objective C is.

```
 - (CLLocationCoordinate2D) getMidPointCoords
 {
    double dLon = (self.toCoordinate.longitude - self.fromCoordinate.longitude) * (M_PI/180);
    double Bx = cos(self.toCoordinate.latitude)*cos(dLon);
    double By = cos(self.toCoordinate.latitude)*sin(dLon);
    double latM = atan2(sin(self.fromCoordinate.latitude)+sin(self.toCoordinate.latitude), sqrt( (cos(self.fromCoordinate.latitude)+Bx)*(cos(self.fromCoordinate.latitude)+Bx) + By*By) );
    double lonM = self.fromCoordinate.longitude + atan2(By, cos(self.fromCoordinate.latitude) + Bx);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D midPoint;
    midPoint.latitude = latM;
    midPoint.longitude = lonM;
 }
```

When I debug this code though it is clearly returning the incorrect coordinates. 
So essentially my Question is "Is this because of the fact that I am using doubles?" or is my implementation of this formula simply flauwed?

Thank you in advance to any assistance, or insight provided.

Comment: So which variable is computed incorrectly? Did you compute the results with a calculator and compared step-by-step?

Comment: Try to compute the delta with ABS(lon1 - lon2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigonometric functions you are using (`sin`, `cos`, `atan2`) require their parameter to be in radians, not degrees.

For example, in this line:

```
double Bx = cos(self.toCoordinate.latitude)*cos(dLon);
```

the `cos(self.toCoordinate.latitude)` is wrong because `self.toCoordinate.latitude` is in degrees but `cos` requires radians.

Everywhere that you call a trigonometric function, first convert the parameter from degrees to radians (multiply degrees by `(M_PI/180.0)`).

In addition, in this line:

```
double lonM = self.fromCoordinate.longitude + atan2(...
```

the `self.fromCoordinate.longitude` also needs to be converted to radians because the rest of the expression is also in radians.

Finally, at the end `latM` and `lonM` will have the midpoint but in radians (not degrees).

So when setting `midPoint.latitude` and `midPoint.longitude`, you have to convert `latM` and `lonM` from radians back to degrees by multiplying them by `(180.0/M_PI)`.

Comment: Ah, knew it was some or other shortfall on my part thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Worked perfectly when conversion where done properly. Thank you very much and in future I will make sure to do a bit more research before just implementing a formula